# kubernetes network policies,allow access to a specific ip

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have the following tasks to perform

1. Create a namespace named forensics
2. All the pods within the forensics namespace should not be able to
   communicate outside the world (egress isolation)
3. Create a pod named investigator in the default namespace.
4. Pods within forensics namespace should only allow connection from IP
   of the investigator pod.

I created the following Yaml to do the same.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  labels:
    name: forensics
  name: forensics

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: forensics
  name: forensics
  namespace: forensics
spec:
  containers:
    - command:
        - sleep
        - "10000"
      image: busybox
      name: forensics
      resources: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: pod1
  name: pod1
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - command:
        - sleep
        - "10000"
      image: busybox
      name: pod1
      resources: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: investigator
  name: investigator
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - command:
        - sleep
        - "10000"
      image: busybox
      name: investigator
      resources: {}
---
#deny all ingress/egress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-ingress
  namespace: forensics
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
---
# allow ingress from IP of  investigator pod
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: investigator-network-policy
  namespace: forensics
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  ingress:
    - from:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 10.244.0.151/32
```

and I can see describe policy as shown

```
**kubectl describe networkpolicy default-deny-ingress -n forensics**
Name:         default-deny-ingress
Namespace:    forensics
Created on:   2020-06-16 18:07:21 +0530 IST
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  Spec:
  PodSelector:     <none> (Allowing the specific traffic to all pods in this namespace)
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    <none> (Selected pods are isolated for ingress connectivity)
  Allowing egress traffic:
    <none> (Selected pods are isolated for egress connectivity)
  Policy Types: Ingress, Egress

 **~/kubectl describe networkpolicy investigator-network-policy -n forensics**
Name:         investigator-network-policy
Namespace:    forensics
Created on:   2020-06-16 18:10:49 +0530 IST
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  Spec:
  PodSelector:     <none> (Allowing the specific traffic to all pods in this namespace)
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: <any> (traffic allowed to all ports)
    From:
      IPBlock:
        CIDR: 10.244.0.151/32
        Except: 
  Not affecting egress traffic
  Policy Types: Ingress
```

But I can not ping forensic pod from the investigator pod.

```
akthakur@ninja k get po -o wide
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
investigator   1/1     Running   0          20s   10.244.0.151   thinking-3qxqs   <none>           <none>
pod1           1/1     Running   0          20s   10.244.0.232   thinking-3qxqs   <none>           <none>
 akthakur@ninja k get po -o wide -n forensics
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
forensics   1/1     Running   0          87s   10.244.0.199   thinking-3qxqs   <none>           <none>
```

Ping results

```
/ # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 62:54:37:84:13:42
          inet addr:10.244.0.151  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:447 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1944 (1.8 KiB)  TX bytes:43078 (42.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

**/ # ping 10.244.0.199
PING 10.244.0.199 (10.244.0.199): 56 data bytes
^C**
--- 10.244.0.199 ping statistics ---
48 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
/ # ping 10.244.0.232
PING 10.244.0.232 (10.244.0.232): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.244.0.232: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.122 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.0.232: seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.169 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.0.232: seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.151 ms
^C
--- 10.244.0.232 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.122/0.147/0.169 ms
/ # %
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you expose your pod? You need to expose the pod with service ?

Comment: No service.Pod to pod communication on IP

Answer (score 1):

Service is one of the mature way to handle pod to pod communication.
By default, pods can communicate with each other by their IP address, regardless of the namespace they're in.
Check your default policy on namespace level. it's set to denied by default if don't specify during namespace creation.
change networkpolicy as shown below to allow traffic from other namespace.

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: some-name
  namespace: forensics
spec:
  selector: all()
  types:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

Comment: I agree service is a mature way but all I want is to test network policies.I am using weave network.. As per requirement, all traffic from all namespaces must be blocked but traffic from a specific pod in a namespace(which is blocked) should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You just allow ingress traffic but blocking egress traffic. So there is no receive packet back to investigator pod.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).